# Pivot table in SQL Server for my displaying total value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display the expense of particular month using pivot table.here i had applied my code for your referal

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(years) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT years FROM pivots) AS years

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =  N'SELECT  DISTINCT months, ' + @ColumnName + FROM pivots
      PIVOT(SUM(expense) FOR  years IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

The output am getting is displayed below

```
    months  2014    2015    2016
    febuary 200 NULL    NULL
    january NULL    100 NULL
    january 500 NULL    NULL
    march   NULL    NULL    300
```

the output which i want is january value should not repeated twice.it should update the value in null place.it should not create another value column

Comment: mysql? are you sure about that?

Comment: Can you add some sample data for the table you are using (pivots)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have another column (or more) in the table pivots that you are not selecting, that varies for the same month. The PIVOT statement will group by all the available columns, not just the ones you select in the output.

Take the following table for example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Pivots (Months VARCHAR(100), Years INT, expense INT, Col INT);
INSERT #Pivots 
VALUES
    ('febuary', 2014, 200, 1),
    ('january', 2014, 500, 1),
    ('january', 2015, 100, 2),
    ('march', 2016, 300, 1);
```

If you run:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Pivots AS p
        PIVOT 
        (   SUM(expense)
            FOR Years IN ([2014], [2015], [2016])
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY months;
```

You can see more clearly why there are two rows for `january` (1 for each value in `Col`):

```
Months  Col 2014    2015    2016
------------------------------
febuary 1   200     NULL    NULL
january 1   500     NULL    NULL
january 2   NULL    100     NULL
march   1   NULL    NULL    300
```

Because `Col` is being fed into the `PIVOT` it is part of the implicit `GROUP BY`, in your case you are not selecting any other columns, so this reason gets distorted.

The way around this is to use a subquery to only select the relevant columns:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  months, years, expense
            FROM    #Pivots
        ) AS p
        PIVOT 
        (   SUM(expense)
            FOR Years IN ([2014], [2015], [2016])
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY months;
```

Which gives the expected results:

```
months  2014    2015    2016
------------------------------
febuary 200     NULL    NULL
january 500     100     NULL
march   NULL    NULL    300
```

So your full query would be:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(years) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT years FROM pivots) AS years;

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =  N'SELECT  DISTINCT months, ' + @ColumnName + 'FROM (SELECT months, years, expense FROM pivots) AS p
      PIVOT(SUM(expense) FOR  years IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;

DROP TABLE #Pivots;
```

For what it is worth, the fastest, and most reliable way to generate your columns is actually to use SQL Server's XML extensions, and also `DISTINCT` in the final query is redundant, you may be better off using:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET  @ColumnName = STUFF((  SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(years)
                            FROM pivots
                            GROUP BY years
                            ORDER BY years
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 'SELECT months, ' + @ColumnName + '
                        FROM (SELECT years, months, expense FROM pivots) AS p
                            PIVOT (SUM(expense) FOR years IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```